# Delete Beta users lists in Android Developer Console

Tags: android, beta-testing

I have some apps published in my android developer account. Some of them are released as closed Beta, where I use lists of users to give them use permissions. Now I have some lists that are old and I don't need them anymore.

The question is: how can I delete (if possible) that lists? I know how to edit them, add and remove users from them, but how to completely delete a list?

I know it sounds easy, but I can't find the way. Maybe someone at Google forgot to put a "delete" button... [because more people are asking for it](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/rcXVNJ4EtBs;context-place=forum/play) or maybe I just can't find it. It's a bit annoying because all my apps share that lists so then I have to select among many useless lists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40):

Finally I found a way to reuse a tester list.

- Open your developer console
- Click "settings" at the bottom in the left navigation bar
- Now, again in the left navigation bar the second item from bottom reads "Manage email lists"
- If you "edit" a list in this view, you can at least change the name of the list
- This is the way to reuse existing lists

I know, this is not the same as a "delete" of a list, but if you just rename a no-longer-used list and fill it with new names it's quite the same.
you can rename your currently not-in-use lists to start with zzz or something to have them at the bottom of the list.

Hope this helps!
Cheers

Comment: Thank you. Was looking for this for some time.

Comment: Great! Thanks :).

Comment: June 2019 and this is still an issue.. Thanks!

Comment: March 2020 and still no option to delete

Comment: With the new Play Console, you can now delete email lists!

Answer (score 7):

You can finally delete an email list on the new Google Play Console. You can activate the new console by going to the new address: https://play.google.com/console

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing this, there's still no way to delete a list. Also there's no way to empty an existing list because a list must have at least one email address. In my case, I ended up changing the list name to a single dot (.) that way it won't be as visible as the actual list that I need. I'm not sure why Google can't provide a simple delete button for this.